# curious affect of led lamps

Tags: electrical

I have a chandelier with 12 led lamps lit by 1 way switch altogether.1 week ago I rewired it to split it into 2 circuits and also to be switched on and off from 2 sides {2 way circuit}.finally put the same led lamps. I noticed that when switch them off they remain little bit on very dim permanently.what causes this effect and how can I remove it?this effect was not shown before re wired it 2 way circuit,with the same lamps.

`

Comment: Controlling a light fixture from two locations is refereed to as a 3-way switch circuit. If you are using simple on/off 3 way switches, there is no reason for lamps to be on. Can you supply a diagram showing how you wired it and what products you used?

Comment: Permanently? Many white LED's use a phosphor that glows for some time after the light is switched off, but not permanently.

Comment: This may be a better question for the [electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) *(If you ask it there, please link to it from the comments here)*

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have the same effect in some of the LEDs in my own home.
I assume you are using a dimmer? What brand and model?

I am using Lightolier electronic dimmers, with LED level indicators on the side. The tiny load the dimmer causes will create current flow through the LED lamps in the fixture. A backlit device can do the same thing.